# Add Custom Shadow to TabBar Layer but also Remove the Shadow Image

Tags: ios, swift, shadow, tabbar

I'd like to add a custom shadow to my TabBar whilst also removing the TabBar's default shadow image (separator line).

I can do either or but not both due to; `.maskToBounds = false` & `.clipsToBounds = true`

Please see my code below;

```
func configureView() {
        tabBar.tintColor = Color.tint
        tabBar.isTranslucent = false
        tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
        tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(named: "background")
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "background")

        tabBar.layer.shadowColor = Color.highlight.cgColor
        tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide more of your code and/or the storyboard layout and screenshots of what you have vs. what you would like it to look like? You also seem to be using a third-party color framework. Can you indicate which one?

Comment: Are you sure you need that `clipsToBounds = true`?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise the 1px tabBar separator is still visible.